# Find unversioned files in CVS checkout

Tags: cvs

CVS doesn't list **unversioned files** in the status output by default, so how can I get a list of all unversioned files? This is the best I've come up with so far:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9
do
    2>/dev/null cvs status "$REPLY" | >/dev/null grep Unknown && echo "$REPLY"
done 9< <( find . \( -type d -name CVS -prune -false \) -o -type f -print0 )
```

Surely there must be a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution: `cvs -qn update`

Comment: I have `alias cvss='cvs -nq update'`, and an alias for `cvs -nq update | grep -v '^?'` for when I work with people who haven't heard of `.cvsignore`. And, strictly speaking, the answer to your question is `cvs -nq update | grep '^?'`.